# Load Balancer not getting Public IP on Azure AKS-engine

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have deployed a cluster on Azure using AKS-engine on a existing VNET. My group has `Owner` permission over resources. Now all my load balancer service is not getting Public IP, it hangs on a `pending` state forever.

```
kubectl describe svc zevac-frontend-lb
Name:                     zevac-frontend-lb
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"zevac-frontend-lb","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"loadBalancerIP":"52.172.46....
Selector:                 app=zevac-frontend
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.0.245.52
IP:                       52.172.46.210
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31723/TCP
Endpoints:                10.0.3.11:80,10.0.3.45:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type     Reason                      Age                From                Message
  ----     ------                      ----               ----                -------
  Warning  CreatingLoadBalancerFailed  6m (x9 over 35m)   service-controller  Error creating load balancer (will retry): failed to ensure load balancer for service default/zevac-frontend-lb: timed out waiting for the condition
  Normal   EnsuringLoadBalancer        1m (x10 over 37m)  service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
```

Comment: Any update? Or if you solve the problem please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

In your issue, I think there are two possible reasons. One is that your public IP is not in the same region with your AKS cluster. I think it's the most possible reason. The other one is your AKS cluster does not have the permission to do that action.

When you use the static public IP, there are also two means. One is in the node group and the other is outside the node group. When you use the public IP outside the node group your AKS cluster should have the "Network Contributor" permission of the group that the public IP in at least. See [Use a static IP address outside of the node resource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip#use-a-static-ip-address-outside-of-the-node-resource-group).

Comment: My public IP and node resources are in the same resource group and location. Also the app has owner permission for both cluster and public IP

Comment: What version of your AKS?

Comment: aks-engine version
Version: v0.31.1
GitCommit: 13c427824
GitTreeState: clean

Comment: I mean when you create the AKS which version do you choose?

Comment: Which resource group does the public IP in?

Comment: I use `aks-engine deploy` command to create the cluster. its not AKS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189437/discussion-between-charles-xu-and-sankycse).

Comment: @sankycse Do you solve the problem? If you solved the problem and the answer works to you, you can accept it. Or you can add the answer for someone who meets a similar problem.

Comment: I solve the problem using azure aks service instead of aks engine

Comment: @sankycse OK, though my answer does not help you, it's still a piece of good news to hear.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, so that in future somebody could save some time. 
`aks-engine` has this bug which is well known. To solve use `aks` service from azure `cli` or management portal which currently support deploying a cluster over an existing VNET.